# IIS / WCF - related concern

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, iis, threadpool

**Background:**
We have a WCF service deployed with the help of IIS in a single server. The service is been configured as per call with concurrency mode as multiple. The IIS server only deploys the mentioned WCF service with no other services or websites.

There are 80-90 clients connects and work with WCF service on a daily basis (24 hrs in a day). Some of these clients connect to service for longer duration and some for short. The duration is purely based on the kind of operation that they request from service and shall span from 1 sec to 60 sec.

When it comes to clients, we have clients those are thick (WPF), thin (web sites), and some other external API consumers.

**Concern:**
We have been facing connectivity issue with this service at least once in a week, which will eventually fixed when we restart the IIS.

**Question:**
Can someone help on;

1. why the connectivity issue resolve once we restart?
2. how thread pool manages in IIS / server clr ?
3. can I provision more servers to fix this forever ?
4. if  answer to 3rd question is 'Yes' then is there any load balancing software    available to address such scenario ?

**More Info:**

Service

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class Implementation : IImplementation
{…}
```

Server configuration
[image]

Comment: Are there any resource leaks (e.g. database connections, external service calls from within your service)? In general, more servers with a balancer sound like hiding issues rather than solving them. There should be no connectivity issues whatsoever - try it with a fake service that does nothing except for accepting connections.

Comment: There is no known resource leaks, since all unmanaged resources are released properly as per guidance. There are external wcf service calls, various web service call (SOAP/XML/Rest) etc. However, all these consumption are properly managed as per guidance.

Comment: Have you observed similar issues with a WCF that does nothing internally except for providing stub/fake data but **does not** use any external resources?

Comment: You can try to optimize the recycling of the application pool, see link: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/recycling

Comment: Pool recycling is something, which I use to do to get around with this before restarting the service. This work if I do on a daily basis to save service from restarting.

Comment: @WiktorZychla, We have integration test stubs, which does what you asked me to do. Correct me if I wrong.

Comment: @Nair: sounds right. But if integration test stubs show **no** connection issues while actual implementations **do show** connection issues then you have issues in implementations of your services. And resource issues are most common.